# How to get only warning errors from PMD through command line

Tags: java, pmd

I want to run pmd from command line, i know how to do it.

```
kumar@anandlinux:~/pmd-bin-5.2.3/bin > ./run.sh pmd -d "/home/kumar/workspace/STA/src/com/sta/" -f html -R java-basic,java-design,java-unusedcode>/tmp/abc.html
```

But i have to categorize the result into various levels like warning urgent etc.

I'm not able to figure out the way for this. If i integrate PMD in eclipse, i get errors categorized on 5 levels. Let's say i just want warning level errors in my output, then how do we get this.

Please help